# Running React - Express App on Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure, express

I am trying to run my web app on azure app service. I have built the client-side with npm create-react-app. Server is built with npm install -g express-generator. The azure app displays my frontend. But I don't know how to run the app.js file

I have the following file structure

```
webapp
 -client
     -src
        App.js
     package.json
-server
     -bin
         www
     app.js
```